# Symfony Ajax Response displays cache header

Tags: symfony

In my ajax response the Cache-Control Header is displayed in the markup.

> HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Date: Thu, 11 Oct 2012
>   09:00:59 GMT

I expected the header to be in the headers and not in the markup.

Here is my controller action excerpt:

```
...
$template = $this->render('list.html.twig', array(
                'data' => $data
                    ));
return new Response($template);
...
```

Why is this and how can i make this disappear?

Comment: Please, add more code samples - how do you handle data in client, etc.

Comment: the view gets fetched via jquery: result_div.load(route);

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The method `render()` display headers.

You can use method `renderView()`. This method don't display headers, just the generate html.

Hope it's helpful. :)

Comment: Thank you!  Best solution for KnpSnappyBundle and wkhtmltopdf

Comment: This was driving me crazy, and this fixed it - thank you!

Answer (score 15):

You can either do

```
$template = $this->render('list.html.twig', array());
return new Response($template->getContent());
```

Or do this

```
$template = $this->renderView('list.html.twig', array());
return new Response($template);
```

Second is more appropriate.

Comment: Not Working in my case.